# difficulty parsing data from google calendar json feed

Tags: jquery, json, google-calendar-api

I am trying to print the event name, event time and link to the calendar from my google calendar. Cant seem to figure out what am I doing wrong

First of all thanks to the community for giving me some solid direction on this one. I am getting the event name correctly. But the event start time and link is showing undefined.

My jquery and html looks like this

```
    var event = '';

var gclaData = 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/somugus%40gmail.com/public/full?orderby=starttime&sortorder=ascending&max-results=3&futureevents=true&alt=json';

$.getJSON(gclaData,function(data){
    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i){
     event += '<div class="eventHolder">'; 
     event += '<div class="eventTime">'+ data.feed.entry[i].gd$when.startTime+"</div>";
     event += '<div class="eventName">'+ data.feed.entry[i].title.$t + "</div>";
     event += '<div class="eLink">'+ data.feed.entry[i].link.href + "</div>";
     event += '</div>';
  });
  $('#output').html(event);
});
```

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/HEZaK/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like

```
$.getJSON(gclaData,function(data){
    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, entry){
        event += '<div class="eventHolder">'; 
        event += '<div class="eventTime">'+ entry.gd$when[0].startTime+"</div>";
        event += '<div class="eventName">'+ entry.title.$t + "</div>";
        event += '<div class="eLink">'+ entry.link[0].href + "</div>";
        event += '</div>';
    });
    $('#output').html(event);
});
```

Few pointers

1. .each() pass the reference to the object as the second argument to the callback, so there is no need to use the index to get the properties
2. `gd$when` property is an array, so you might need to access the first element
3. same of `link` property also

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bGdhD/)

Comment: @Arun-- amazing. You literally solved my problem :-).. Thanks