# Trying to read the Google Calender JSON Data using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-calendar-api

I am trying to read the google calendar events from the JSON response but nothing happens.
I have tried the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519881/difficulty-parsing-data-from-google-calendar-json-feed) but that too is not working. I am adding the code to my CMS and when I check on the front end, nothing appears. I even tried running this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bGdhD/ but this also doesn't provide any response.

My google calendar URL is

https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/varun.luthra.72%40gmail.com/public/full?alt=json-in-script&max-results=25&singleevents=false&futureevents=true&sortorder=descending&orderby=starttime

```
<script>
var event = '';

var gclaData = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/varun.luthra.72%40gmail.com/public/full?alt=json-in-script&max-results=25&singleevents=false&futureevents=true&sortorder=descending&orderby=starttime';


$.getJSON(gclaData,function(data){
    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, entry){
        event += '<div class="eventHolder">'; 
        event += '<div class="eventTime">'+ entry.gd$where[0].startTime+"</div>";
        event += '<div class="eventName">'+ entry.title.$t + "</div>";
        event += '<div class="eLink">'+ entry.link[0].href + "</div>";
        event += '</div>';
    });
    $('#output').html(event);
});
</script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

**Also, could this be a cross domain issue?**

Answer (score 0):

It's not a cross domain problem, because the response includes the [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) header:

```
access-control-allow-origin:*
```

The problem is the response is a JSONP response and so includes a callback function. This makes it invalid JSON (unless you strip the callback).

**Option 1**: If you set `&callback=?` in the URL, jQuery will treat the response as JSONP:

```
var gclaData = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/varun.luthra.72%40gmail.com/public/full?alt=json-in-script&max-results=25&singleevents=false&futureevents=true&sortorder=descending&orderby=starttime&callback=?';
```

**Option 2**: Use `$.ajax()` and strip the callback:

```
gdata.io.handleScriptLoaded(
```

Also strip the closing parenthesis and semicolin `);`. This leaves you with a valid JSON response, which needs to be decoded from a string to a Javascript object using `JSON.parse()` or similar.

---

Also, there doesn't appear to be an `entry` array or object in the response, so you need to modify your success event accordingly.

Last point, this will not work:

```
entry.gd$where[0]
```

If the variable name has special characters, use the `[]` notation:

```
entry['gd$where'][0]
```